# Load audio/images from url, download and save the audio/images for offline mode ionic 5 (angular)

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

In my case, when the photos or audio files have been loaded from firebase or played, they should be accessible offline and shouldn't need to be loaded from the URL again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For that case try saving it to sqlite. Data does not persist when you close the application. So I suggest try to store the data on sqlite. Here's a [tutorial](https://www.positronx.io/ionic-sqlite-database-crud-app-example-tutorial/) on how to implement it.